# How can i grab the last 10 entries from my database and display them in my view with the last entry starting first?

Tags: codeigniter, blogs

Im am currently working on a blog that displays text below the text box as soon as you post an entry. At the moment my page displays the first 10 entries from the database base with the oldest starting first. How can i make the latest 10 entries display with the latest blog displaying first?

Here is my controller:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

public function _construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("Blogmodel"); 
    $this->load->model("profiles");

}


public function index()
{

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

    $viewData['username'] = $username;

    $this->load->model('Blogmodel');


    if($this->input->post('act') =='create_post')
    {
        $this->Blogmodel->insert_entry();

    }


    $viewData['blogs'] = $this->Blogmodel->get_last_ten_entries();

    $this->load->view('shared/header');  
    $this->load->view('blog/blogtitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->helper('form');// Load the form helper.

    // Lets set the stuff that will be getting pushed forward...
    $data = array();
    $data['form_open']=form_open();
    $data['form_title'] = form_input(array('name' => 'title'));
    $data['form_text'] = form_textarea(array('name' => 'text'));
    $data['form_hidden'] = form_hidden('act','create_post');
    $data['form_submit'] = form_submit('submit','Make Post');


    $this->load->view('blog/post', $data);
    $this->load->view('blog/blogview');


       $this->load->view('shared/footer');
    }

   }
```

Here is my model:

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model
 {

 function Blogmodel()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  } 

public function get_last_ten_entries()// this is the function that grabs the entries from my blogs database
{
    $query = $this->db->get('blogs', 10);
    return $query->result();

    }
public function insert_entry()
{
    $this->title = $this->input->post('title');
    $this->body = $this->input->post('text');
    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
    $this->date = date("Y-m-d");

    $this->db->insert('blogs', $this);


}
```

}

View:

```
 <?foreach($blogs AS $viewData)
 {
$id = $viewData->id;
$title = $viewData->title;
$body = $viewData->body;
$username = $viewData->username;
$date = $viewData->date;

?>

   <b> <?=$title?></b>
    <p><?=$body?></p>

      <p>posted by:<?=$username?></p>
      <p>date: <?=$date?></p>

<hr>

  <?
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just order your results by the id field (if you have one in your table)

```
public function get_last_ten_entries()
{
     $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');    
     $query = $this->db->get('blogs', 10);
    return $query->result();

 }
```

or add a timestamp while adding rows in the database, and then sort the results on that column.

```
public function insert_entry()
{
    $this->timestamp = time();
    $this->title = $this->input->post('title');
    $this->body = $this->input->post('text');
    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
    $this->date = date("Y-m-d");

    $this->db->insert('blogs', $this);   
}

public function get_last_ten_entries()
{
    $this->db->order_by('timestamp', 'DESC');    
    $query = $this->db->get('blogs', 10);
    return $query->result();        
}
```